# Understanding exim configuration files on Debian/Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, debian, configuration, exim

I want to understand what's going on with this Exim configuration directory.

In /etc/exim4, there's:

```
* exim4.conf.template
* update-exim4.conf.conf
* conf.d
```

The conf.d has a mess of directories and files, and inside each are **a bunch of if statements** which I find really different.

For example:

```
maildir_home:
  debug_print = "T: maildir_home for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = appendfile
  .ifdef MAILDIR_HOME_MAILDIR_LOCATION
  directory = MAILDIR_HOME_MAILDIR_LOCATION
  .else
  directory = $home/Maildir
  .endif
  .ifdef MAILDIR_HOME_CREATE_DIRECTORY
  create_directory
  .endif
  .ifdef MAILDIR_HOME_CREATE_FILE
```

My question is,

-where do the CAPS VARIABLES get defined?

- how can I change them?
- why are there so many if statements in these configuration files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is Debian/Ubuntu's way of managing Exim4. You'll need to limit yourself to using the `dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config` utility and it's config file, `update-exim4.conf.conf` to manage it, or, just blow it all away and manage it all yourself. Check out:

http://pkg-exim4.alioth.debian.org/README/README.Debian.html#completely-different-configuration

Comment: Using a completely different configuration is not advised. It can break on updates and packages that automatically add stuff to the `conf.d` directory to configure exim will not work.

Comment: This is mostly FUD.  Exim has very strong backwards compatibility for configurations and won't break on updates.  You only lose the automated support for other packages to insert mail-handling.  You gain a configuration which doesn't have a pre-processor and config files used for building a config file.

General statements "X is not advised" should be perhaps be reserved for where there is little disagreement.

Answer (score 10):

Here's the easy guide to understand Debian's exim config:

1. `conf.d` has the configuration snippets, separated by config area. The variables in caps are normally defined on the first part (called base, if my memory serves me).
2. the `exim4.conf.template` is generated by concatenating all the snippets at install time, so the basic configuration is the same.
3. the config file used by the daemon is created on a different directory based on one of the above templates.
4. Each time you use `update-exim4.conf` it generates a new config file, based on what you answered when the package configuration asked about split configuration.

If you use the split configuration, you have to use files at `conf.d` to manage exim, otherwise use the `exim4.conf.template`.

I suggest you use the `conf.d` scheme, after you get used to it its easier to manage and add/remove stuff. Read all the files in all dirs and compare it to the running config file (`/var/lib/exim4/config.autogenerated` but comments are striped so re-run `update-exim4.conf --keepcomments`, or you can use `exim -bP` to see the running config too) and you will get it real easy.

Most of the times you will not need any special configuration, so just use `dpkg-reconfigure`exim4-config` and answer the questions.

Answer (score 1):

Those are not really exim configuration files those are part of the debian configuration system that is used to generate the actually exim configuration file.