# SMTP unroutable address

Tags: email, smtp, exim, g-suite

I have set up gmail google app accounts for our own domain, `domain.com`, so that email is handled by gmail. I.e. MX records point to google servers, A records to our own server IP. This works fine.

Now I tried sending emails from **our machine** (via `crontab`, using Debian's `exim4`) to **our own email address**, e.g. `admin@domain.com`.

This doesn't work. Presumably exim is seeing the address as local and fails to forward it to the google servers. The delivery fails with:

```
Subject: Mail delivery failed: returning message to sender

This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

  admin@domain.com
    Unrouteable address
```

and is then unhelpfully delivered to `/var/mail`.

Emails to other addresses -- outside of `domain.com` -- work ok.

I looked at the configs under `/etc/exim4/conf.d/` but couldn't make sense of it.

Any help is welcome. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating a new router, inside the `.ifdef DCconfig_internet` block:

```
my_domain:
  debug_print = "R: dnslookup for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = dnslookup
  domains = domain.com
  transport = remote_smtp
  # ignore private rfc1918 and APIPA addresses
  ignore_target_hosts = 0.0.0.0 : 127.0.0.0/8 : 192.168.0.0/16 :\
                        172.16.0.0/12 : 10.0.0.0/8 : 169.254.0.0/16 :\
                        255.255.255.255
  no_more
```

This forces a remote delivery (via standard dnslookup) even for `*@domain.com` addresses, which is exactly what I wanted.

There may be an easier way to achieve this, by modifying the existing routers, but this "works for me".

Comment: oh man i love you, you saved a lot of my time

Answer (score 0):

The domain `domain.com` is invalid or has a bad DNS setup. It could even resolve to an IP in private address space. As you redacted the real domain, there is no much more information we can provide.